# Filter to sort in angular js for JSON data

Tags: arrays, angularjs, json, sorting, angularjs-filter

I am new to angular js and have basic understanding of how filters work in angular js.I am stuck to sort my jSON data array as there are various parameters on which it has to get sorted.

My JSON array is in this format:

```
[
  {
     type:0,
     emp_name:"xyz",
     connected_on:"9876543210"
  },
  {
     type:1,
     emp_name:"",
     connected_on:"9876543210"
  },
  {
     type:1,
     emp_name:"abcd",
     connected_on:"9876543210"
  },
  {
     type:0,
     emp_name:"pqr",
     connected_on:"9876543210"
  }
]
```

Other combination of the same array can be:

```
[
  {
     type:0,
     emp_name:"",
     connected_on:"9876543210"
  },
  {
     type:1,
     emp_name:"xyz",
     connected_on:"9876543210"
  },
  {
     type:0,
     emp_name:"abcd",
     connected_on:"9876543210"
  }
]
```

Every array will  have any one object where  **type:1** , will be there and after sorting it has to be the first element always.

After that,the sorted array should have all those elements whose **emp_name:""** is there.

At last of the sorted array it should contain all the remaining elements sorted according to **emp_name:"whatever names"**

So the results should look something like this below:

```
[
  {
     type:1,
     emp_name:"xyz",
     connected_on:"9876543210"
  },
  {
     type:0,
     emp_name:"",
     connected_on:"9876543210"
  },
  {
     type:0,
     emp_name:"abcd",
     connected_on:"9876543210"
  }
]
```

Can anyone help me to write the filter to get the desired result.Thanks in advance.If any other info required please let me know.

Also connected_on is unique value so i am using **track by JSONarr.connected_on**

Comment: Lodash has a function for this: https://lodash.com/docs#orderBy if you would consider ordering the array on load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort function expect `-1`, `0`, `-1` as result. `-1` means before, 0 means no change and 1 means later.

Now you have to sort based on 2 parameters, so its better to have an arithmetic value. Have higher value based on priority. So in following situation, we have to sort first based on `type` and then based on `emp_name`.

To sort ascending, return 1 for greater and -1 for smaller. For descending reverse the values. Now combining this for both keys you will get something like this:

```js
var data=[{type:0,emp_name:"xyz",connected_on:"9876543210"},{type:1,emp_name:"",connected_on:"9876543210"},{type:1,emp_name:"abcd",connected_on:"9876543210"},{type:0,emp_name:"pqr",connected_on:"9876543210"}];

data.sort(function(a, b) {
  var _a = a.type > b.type ? -10 : a.type < b.type ? 10 : 0;
  var _b = a.emp_name > b.emp_name ? 1 : a.emp_name < b.emp_name ? -1 : 0;
  return _a + _b;
});
console.log(data)
```

Comment: thanks,it worked like charm,i missed the trick to take it -10

Comment: Glad, was able to help you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your array name emplist. You can search anything here. You will get the desired result. Use table for searching the data.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search">
  <table>
    <th>type</th>
    <th>Emp name</th>
    <th>connected on</th>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in emplist|filter:search">
       <td>{{item.type}}<td>
       <td>{{item.emp_name}}<td>
       <td>{{item.connected_on}}<td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: I dont have to search , i just need to order the elements while displaying using filter created in my controller.